# Create SIMBL Plugin in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, plugins, nsmenuitem, nsmenu, simbl

I want to make a very basic SIMBL Plugin - just add a new Menu in Safari.
This is what I've tried:
I added this to my plist:

```
<key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
<string>MySamplePlugin</string>
<key>SIMBLTargetApplications</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>BundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.Safari</string>
        <key>MaxBundleVersion</key>
        <string>*</string>
        <key>MinBundleVersion</key>
        <string>*</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Then i created the MySamplePlugin classes and a Menu.xib. (All connections are made this can't be the mistake)
my .h

```
-(IBAction)clickAbout:(id)sender;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSMenu *topMenu;
```

and my .main file

```
- (id) init {
self = [super init];
if (! self)
    return nil;

[NSBundle loadNibNamed: @"Menu.xib" owner: self];
return self;
}

- (IBAction) clickAbout: (id) sender {
 NSLog(@"do some stuff here");
}



+ (void) load
{
MySamplePlugin* plugin = [MySamplePlugin sharedInstance];
NSMenuItem* item;

item = [[NSMenuItem alloc] init];
[item setSubmenu: [plugin topMenu]];

[[plugin topMenu] setTitle: @"George"];

[[NSApp mainMenu] addItem: item];

NSLog(@"MySamplePlugin installed");
}

+ (MySamplePlugin*) sharedInstance
{
static MySamplePlugin* plugin = nil;

if (plugin == nil)
    plugin = [[MySamplePlugin alloc] init];

return plugin;
}
```

Any idea why my plugin is not working ? It builds without warnings and i copy it to ~/Library/Application Support/SIMBL/Plugins/

And this is my console.app output: http://cl.ly/LsH9

Comment: Any chance you could be a bit more specific? In what sense is it not working?

Comment: it doesn't display anything. The menu is not shown.

Comment: What have you done to debug it already (this is for people to avoid suggestions that you have already tried)?

Comment: not much, because i don't get an error. Everything compiles. An plugin, topMenu and item are not nil. Also i had a look at the console.app output (which i posted above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind i got it with this little code modification:

```
 NSMenu* mainMenu = [NSApp mainMenu];

NSMenu* debugMenu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@"Menu"];
NSMenuItem* newItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item" action:nil keyEquivalent:@""];

[newItem setSubmenu:debugMenu];
[mainMenu addItem:newItem];
[debugMenu addItemWithTitle:@"Run Unit Tests" action:nil keyEquivalent:@""];
```